# How to style the text inside input tag?

Tags: css

I am trying to style the input tag. I have inserted style tag but it does not work.

```
    <span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
        <label style="color:#666666;"> Warranty </label>
        <input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="warranty" value="true">Yes</input>
        <input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="warranty" value="false">No</input>
    </span>
```

Comment: radio buttons are browser native and are not stylable. you need to implement yourself the part that you want to style, like in haroon's answer.

Comment: Are you trying to style the radio button or the text?

Comment: @rrowland: I am trying to style the text.

Comment: Wrong syntax, `input` is a void element that cannot contain any text nodes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use below code..

```
<span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
    <label style="color:blue;"> Warranty </label>
<input style="color:#666666;" type="radio" name="warranty" value="true" /> <span style="color:red">Yes</span>
<input type="radio" name="warranty" value="false" /><span style="color: red;">NO</span>
</span>
```

[jsfiddle Preview](https://jsfiddle.net/uuLkb9g2/)

you can use span tags for style with input radio.

Comment: That's a pitty the validated answer is probably the least correct one... encouraging inline styles is a bad idea, as is using non-semantic tags when semantic tags exist...

Comment: I understand what he asked for and told him how to do Bartdude and the_monster is your answer isnt corrected by the questioner doesnt mean your answer is correct..

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not correct for several reasons. you should try to use semantic code and avoid using inline styles (use external CSS with proper selector instead)

**The (suggested) markup :**

```
<span class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
    <h3>Warranty</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="warranty" id="warranty_yes" value="true" /><label for="waranty_yes">Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="warranty" id="warranty_no" value="false" /><label for="waranty_yes" />No</label>
</span>
```

**The CSS:** :

```
label {color:#666;}
```

Note : the selector is very generic and will target all `<label>` tags, you might want to target specific ones by use of different css classes on different label tags...

**Fiddle if needed...**

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xmrddq7w/)

**Why not using inline styles ?**

This is considered a bad practice for several reasons. The main reasons I would mention are :

- Ease of maintenance : if you ever wish to change the color, it's better to update only 1 CSS file than all your "style" attributes in all your pages
- Separation of concerns : HTML should contain only content, all layout/UI should be moved somewhere else (CSS file). The same goes for inline javascript which should be avoided and replaced by extrnal JS file/
- Lower specificity : [What is specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

**Why using semantic code is better ?**

This case is a good example of better semantic = better UX. When you use the `<label>` tag, you can link it to the desired control by using the `for` attribute with the value corresponding to the id of the related input element. By doing this, you will allow your users to check the radiobutton/checkbox only by clicking on the label text, they don't have to aim at the button self, which improves UX especially on smaller devices. If you use `<label>` together with a text input, clicking the label puts the focus (cursor) on the text field, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to style the text: Radio inputs don't contain text. You'll want to place the accompanying text in a label, which you can color:

```
<div class="form-group has-failure has-feedback">
  <label style="color:#666666;"> Warranty </label>
  <input type="radio" name="warranty" value="true"/>
  <label style="color:#666666;">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="warranty" value="false"/>
  <label style="color:#666666;">No</label>
</div>
```

I would not recommend using spans because form labels belong in labels, not spans.

Answer (score -1):

The color property in CSS is for the font color or textcolor, maybe take a look at this link. There's a lot of information about styling inputs.

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953

HTML:

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1">Check Box 1</label>
```

CSS:

```
    input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(check_radio_sheet.png) left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thats true, ill include the essential parts